# how to disable the maximise button in eclipse plugin development project

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

i am developing a plugin project. I want to disable the maximize button in the title bar of the wizard page. 
please help me

Comment: Are you using `WizardDialog` to display the wizard?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog` to open the wizard you could create a subclass to set a different shell style in the constructor:

```
public class WizardDialogNoMax extends WizardDialog
{
  public WizardDialogNoMax(Shell parentShell, IWizard wizard)
  {
    super(parentShell, wizard);

    setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.RESIZE | getDefaultOrientation());
  }
}
```

The above is just leaving out the SWT.MAX style. On Mac OSX it is also necessary to leave out SWT.RESIZE (which also means the dialog cannot be resized).

If you are adding a wizard to the Eclipse New, Import or Export wizard extension points then I don't think you can change the maximize button.

Comment: we are not using wizardDialog

Comment: it will extend wizard

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using SHELL and the problem is shell.setSize(x,y) and other shell functions like shell.setMinimumSize(x,y) has no effects.. am i right? can someone pls give an explanation for this.

I face a similar problem in my project.

Also when i use something like

```
public static final int SHELL_TRIM = CLOSE | TITLE | MIN | MAX | RESIZE;
```

i get errors like this : **CLOSE cannot be resolved to a variable**... the same for TITLE, MIN, MAX, RESIZE.

how to proceed now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you only want to remove the maximize button:

```
frame.setResizable(false);
```

example code for a small project of mine:

```
public UI() {
    initComponents();
    this.setResizable(false);
}
```

how it works: 
`initComponents` initializes my GUI which I build from the standard GUI builder in netbeans (you can also download swingbuilder for Eclipse, or just build your GUI yourself).

`this` is my GUI itself which contains my JFrame.

`this` has a method called `setResizable()` which disables or enables the maximise button

Hope this helped

Comment: iam not using JFrames, I am using SWT

Comment: Allright are you using a `shell` ? if so try to use this piece of code:
`Shell yourShell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN );`

Comment: in which class i should place this code in my wizard pages?        i have placed it in the class where the title for the wizard pages is given but it is giving error SWT.Exception invalid thread access